# An ETL software that can identify common columns between tables and append on those columns

Tags: linux, database, data-extraction

I have a bunch of tables with some common columns but completely independent data. I want to create a single large table by appending the data from all of the tables. However, I only want the columns that are common between all of these tables.

One issue is that there are hundreds of columns and about a million rows each. So each table is around 1gb. I was running into memory issues when trying to manipulate the data in some software like Rapidminer.

Any suggestions about a software that could do this? Oh yes, and I run linux x64, so hopefully the software would run on that platform as well.

Comment: Please give an exact example

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

- Can handle large data sets well
- Cross Platform - including Linux
- Free, Gratis & Open Source

I would suggest coming up with a list of the "Common" columns first and then for each dataset loading it, deleting the unneeded columns and then merging.

Comment: Thanks steve. I ended up using a combo of just sql with some pandas and sqlalchemy. I was able to run an intersection and reduce on the column names between tables. So that worked out well. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: In order to help others in future, pelase either accept Steve's answer, possibly editing it if necessary, or post and accept your own answer.